# MVC 3 CheckBox value OnChange, resubmit form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I have a form with a checkbox in it, a textbox and a button. Whenever the button is clicked, it resubmits the form with whatever is in the textBox and checkBox. But whenever the checkBox changes, I also want it to resubmit the form. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a bit of javascript that fires on the checkbox change, the jQuery below would do it -

```
$('#gosubmit').change(function () {
    //submit form
});
```